# reducing the javascript with multiple hide/show divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide, reduce

I'm hoping that someone would be kind enough to help me.

I have patched together a script to create a set of thumbnails that when hovered over display a link that will show further information in a slide up div.

I need multiple instances of this which I have managed to create but whenever I would like to add a *new project* (which is what these thumbnails will be) I have to add to the javascript every time I add an instance. I need this to work with a CMS so adding to the javascript is out of the question.

My understanding of javascript is not good enough to work out how to reduce the JS and not have to add `$("#projectX").slideDown(500);` even time I add a new project. The code I have so far is below. I basically don't want to have to write a piece of javascript every time I input another thumbnail and slide up div pairing.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="hidden-work">
        <div id="project1" class="hidden">
        <div class="callbacks_container">
          <button class="hide">X</button>
            <ul class="rslides" id="slider2">
            <li>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                    <img src="img/eejits/fleur.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h3>Slide 1</h3>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    </div><!--caption-->
                  </div><!--col-->                    
              </div><!--row--> 
            </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--callbacks_container-->
      </div><!--eejits-->

      <div id="project2" class="hidden">
        <div class="callbacks_container">
        <button class="hide">X</button>
          <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
            <li>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                    <img src="img/eejits/fleur.jpg" alt="">   
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h3>Slide 2</h3>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    </div><!--caption-->
                  </div><!--col-->                    
              </div><!--row--> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div><!--project2 (reach)-->
      <div id="project3" class="hidden">
        <div class="callbacks_container">
        <button class="hide">X</button>
          <ul class="rslides" id="slider3">
            <li>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                    <img src="img/eejits/fleur.jpg" alt=""> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h3>Slide 3</h3>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    </div><!--caption-->
                  </div><!--col-->                    
              </div><!--row--> 
            </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
        </div><!--project3-->
      </div><!--work-->
    </div>

  </div><!--row-->
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="thumb-bg">
        <div class="thumb no1">
          <div class="content">
            <h3>Thumb 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
            <button class="project1 link">VIEW MORE</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--col-->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="thumb-bg">
        <div class="thumb no2">
          <div class="content">
            <h3>Thumb 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
            <button class="project2 link">VIEW MORE</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--col-->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="thumb-bg">
        <div class="thumb no3">
          <div class="content">
            <h3>Thumb 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
            <button class="project3 link">VIEW MORE</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--col-->
  </div><!--row-->
```

JS:

```
   $(function () {
      $("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        pager: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        before: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
        },
        after: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
        }
      });

    });

    $(function () {
      $("#slider2").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        pager: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        before: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
        },
        after: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
        }
      });

    });

    $(function () {
      $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        pager: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        before: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
        },
        after: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
        }
      });

    });


      $(document).ready(function(){   
      $(".project2").click(function(){
        $("#project2").slideDown(500);
        $("#project1").slideUp(500);
        $("#project3").slideUp(500);
      });

      $(".project1").click(function(){
        $("#project1").slideDown(500);
        $("#project2").slideUp(500);
        $("#project3").slideUp(500);
      });

      $(".project3").click(function(){
        $("#project3").slideDown(500);
        $("#project1").slideUp(500);
        $("#project2").slideUp(500);
      });

      $(".hide").click(function(){
        $("#project1").slideUp(500);
        $("#project2").slideUp(500);
        $("#project3").slideUp(500);
      });
    });
```

I really hope that makes sense and any help with this would be brilliant.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into the different selector type.  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/  Anything prefaced with a `#` is referencing an element by `id` (which should be unique and thus only return 1 element) anything prefaced with a `.` refers to elements by `class`

**EDIT:**
Just realised you need to manipulate a separate element to the one that is clicked.  OK so to make sure this works universally, you need to make sure the order is the same for the "buttons" and the "slides".  We're going to find the `index` of the button clicked and then use that same logic to slide the appropriate `divs`.
You can give your buttons a class of "project-button" and your projects a class of "project"

So to make your code universally applicable with one listener you could give all your `projects` a class of `project` and then do something like this:

```
// Attach the same click listener to all elements which have class `project-button`
$('.project-button').on('click', function () {
    // Get the index of this clicked button
    var myIndex = $(this).index();
    // Now get the corresponding `slide`
    var mySlide = $('.project').get(myIndex);
    // Get all `.project`'s then exclude `mySlide`and slide up
    $('.project').not(mySlide).slideUp(500);
    // Now slide down just `mySlide`
    $(mySlide).slideDown(500);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/jPyk6/

Comment: That sounds about right! I will try it out this afternoon and let you know how it goes. Thank you!!!

Comment: @EmilyTurnipTaylor I have update my answer based on being enlightened by a comment from user264....

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```
$(".hidden").click(function(){;
    $(this).slideDown(500);
    ($(this).siblings()).each(function( index ) {
      $( this ).slideUp(500);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you use `class="link"` for every buttons, you can use `class` instead of `id`. Then add `id` to the button for selecting the right `div`, like this:

HTML

```
<button id="project1" class="project1 link">VIEW MORE</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    //slideUp all div with class hidden
    $('div.hidden').slideUp(500);
    //slideDown div with id equals the clicked button
    $('div#'+$(this).attr('id')).slideDown(500);
});
```

I think the same goes for your slider, use the `class` instead of the `id`, like this:

```
$(function () {
  $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
    auto: false,
    pager: false,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    namespace: "callbacks",
    before: function () {
      $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
    },
    after: function () {
      $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
    }
  });
});
```

Note: I don't see any element with class `events`, so I assume its a global element..

Comment: Sometimes there may not be an `id` in relation to `$('div#'+$(this).attr('id')).slideDown(500);` so in that case `$(this).slideDown(500);` will suffice.

Comment: I don't see your point because I suggest him to add an id in every buttons. So there always be a relation between the button and the div.

Actually, I don't think that your answer will work.. Because he want to slideUp/slideDown a **div** when a **button** that has corresponding class with the **div** id is being clicked, e.g. `$(".project1").click`.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean.  There are actually different divs as opposed to the div itself.  Quite right, my bad.  I have updated my answer.